# Show that maximal ideal space of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is empty?

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Show that maximal ideal space of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is empty?

how to approach this problem ?? what i know is that it is non commutative Banach algebra with unity.any hint ??

Comment: It is not empty, as it contains the zero ideal. The ring of matrices over a field is a simple ring.

Comment: @egreg Given that he mentions Banach algebras it seems pretty likely that by "maximal ideal space" he meant "set of non-zero complex homomorphisms".

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich exactly. But how to show that?

Comment: There is only one irrep of $M_n(\mathbf{C})$, and it's not one-dimensional, so there is no ring homomorphism $M_n(\mathbf{C}) \to \mathbf{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n\geq2$ and $\alpha:M_n(\mathbb C)\to\mathbb C$ is an algebra homomorphism, $$\alpha(E_{kk})=\alpha(E_{k1}E_{1k})=\alpha(E_{k1})\alpha(E_{1k})=\alpha(E_{1k})\alpha(E_{k1})=\alpha(E_{1k}E_{k1})=\alpha(E_{11}).$$ Then 
$$
0=\alpha(0)=\alpha(E_{11}E_{22})=\alpha(E_{11})\alpha(E_{22})=\alpha(E_{11})^2. 
$$
Thus $\alpha(E_{11})=0$, and 
$$
\alpha(I)=\sum_k\alpha(E_{kk})=0,
$$
so $\alpha=0$.

Comment: how is $\alpha(E_{k1}E_{1k})=\alpha(E_{1k}E_{k1})$??

Comment: Because $\alpha$ is multiplicative, and $\mathbb C$ is commutative. I added a couple more steps.

Comment: ya . i got it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can play the game to show that $E_{ij}AE_{kl}=a_{jk}E_{il}$, where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is $1$ and all other entries are $0$.

With such, one can show that every two-sided ideal of $M_{n}(R)$ has the form $M_{n}(I)$ for some two-sided ideal $I$ of $R$.

And a consequence is that, if $D$ is a division ring, then $M_{n}(D)$ is simple, which means that $M_{n}(D)$ has no submodule $M\ne 0,S$.

${\bf{C}}$ is a division ring, so the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Of course we assume that $n>1$.

Say $\phi$ is a (nonzero) complex homomorphism of $M_n(\Bbb C)$. Let $A$ be the subalgebra consisting of the diagonal matrices. Then $A$ is canonically isomorphic to $C(K)$, where $K=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Since every complex homomorphism of $C(K)$ is given by evaluation at a point of $K$ we obtain
$\newcommand\diag{\text{diag}}$

> > There exists $j$ such that $\phi(\diag(d_1,\dots,d_n))=d_j$ for every $\diag(d_1,\dots, d_n)\in A$.

*But* if $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ then $y=\diag(d_{\sigma(1)},\dots,d_{\sigma(n)})$ is similar to $x=\diag(d_1,\dots,d_n)$. Hence $\phi(y)=\phi(x)$. With the above this shows that $d_j=d_k$ for every $d_j,d_k\in\Bbb C$.